whitespace-mode: Only display leading whitespace
I want to preface this question by stating that I read: How to display and format leading spaces (spaces at the beginning of a line) with whitespace-mode?
However, it's not solving my problem.
I want whitespace-mode to only show leading spaces (trailing spaces would be ideal; yet not necessary).
By default, it looks like this:

Where every single spaces has a glyph. (Btw, the image is also my whitespace config).
However, I'd like to only have those glyphs for leading spaces. That configuration is described in the whitespace-space-regexp docstring. However, when I enter the recommended regexp:
    (setq whitespace-space-regexp "\\( +\\)")

I get the following:

As you can see, the regexp is doing something, the inner spaces are "different". The inner spaces are not greyed out, whilst thed leading spaces are. However, I'd like for the inner spaces to disappear completely.
What am I missing? Thanks in advance
Here's the code for reference:
(use-package whitespace
  :config
  (progn
    (setq whitespace-line-column (* fill-column 2)) ;; Highlight lines if twice the amount of fill-column
    (setq whitespace-space-regexp "\\(^ +\\| +$\\)") ;; visualize only leading SPACEs.
    ;; (setq whitespace-space-regexp "\\( +\\)")
    ;; (setq whitespace-hspace-regexp "\\(^\xA0+\\|\xA0+$\\)")
    (setq whitespace-display-mappings (assq-delete-all 'newline-mark whitespace-display-mappings))
    (add-to-list 'whitespace-display-mappings '(newline-mark ?\n [92 ?n ?\n][?$ ?\n]))

    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'whitespace-mode)
    (add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'whitespace-mode)
    )
  )



Your subject says "leading" and your body text says "leading and trailing".  Please clarify the question.

In case it's mostly trailing whitespace you care about, see also C-h v show-trailing-whitespace

AFAIK you can't have only some of the spaces displayed as .
The glyph is set via buffer-display-table which is, as the name suggests, applicable to the whole buffer.
(equal (aref buffer-display-table 32) [?·]) => t
(A regular space being ascii 32.)
If you need this, my only suggestion (untested) is that you:

Don't use space-mark (which produces the above) in your whitespace-style
Customize the face used by whitespace mode for the spaces you care about
Tell that face to use a font which renders spaces as dots


How can I modify the face used by whitespace?

M-x customize-group RET whitespace
